# Why don't the edge lengths update after I've scaled my object?

Tags: edges, scale, measurement

In Blender you can turn on edge lengths by going into edit mode and then turning it on in the overlays menu. However, whenever I scale up the object,the lengths stay the exact same which should be impossible. If something is 2 meters and you scale it up to 3 times it's size, it doesn't make sense how it would stay the same. Does anyone have an explanation for this, or for how to fix it?

Comment: One of the fundamentals  of 3d maths is which coordinate space is used. Mesh coordinates are local. For default cube,  It's origin point is local coordinate (0, 0, 0)  One corner is at local coordinate ` (1, 1, 1)`   Scaling the cube object does not change the local coordinate of the vertices and hence neither the edge length or face area.  To apply the scale to local coords,apply scale  (ctrl-A scale) or scale in edit mode.

Comment: Yep, you didn't really change the cube actual dimensions, you only applied a "visual factor" over it. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation-to-an-objects-data/7349#7349